# Display result in graph based on combination of year and month selection in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder

i am display graph of sum of qty datewise it works but now i want to display graph in which sum of qty of month and year combine selection. My date is stored in format `2020-02-14` and i want to display sum of qty of `2020-02` that is from `2019-02 to 2020-09`. I tried lot of works. I am getting graph date wise but now i want to year and month combine

For date selection the query as

```
$get_details=DB::select('SELECT sum(orders_qty) as sum_of_qty,deliver_date FROM `orders` WHERE deliver_date between ? AND ? GROUP BY deliver_date',[$data['start_date'],$data['end_date']]);
```

For yearand month selection i need query
I tried like this

```php
    $data=$req->all();

    $results = DB::table('orders')
                         ->select(DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(deliver_date,"%y-%m") as deliver_date'),DB::raw('SUM(orders_qty) as sum_of_qty'))
                         ->whereBetween('deliver_date',[$data['start_year_month'],$data['end_year_month']])
                         ->groupBy('deliver_date')
                         ->get();
    $date[start_year_month]='2019-02' $date[end_year_month]='2019-05' and actual database date='2019-02-14'
```

plz need query

Comment: what's the problem?

Comment: @TsaiKoga actually date is stored in year-month-day format and now i am select only year and month from input type and in query it can not match how i am extract year-month combination from date like year-month and get sum of qty depends on year-month

Comment: @TsaiKoga are you getting or not?

Comment: is `$data['start_year_month']` this variable `y-m` format?

Comment: @TsaiKoga yes sir and it not compared with date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use `%Y-%m` instead of `%y-%m`;

Secondly, you are rewrite your field's name, so group by will not using the name that has been rewritten, you need to specify `DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(deliver_date,"%Y-%m")`

So the query like this:

```php
$data=$req->all();

$results = DB::table('orders')
                ->select(DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(deliver_date,"%Y-%m") as delivery_date'),DB::raw('SUM(orders_qty) as sum_of_qty'))
                         ->whereBetween(DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(deliver_date,"%Y-%m")'), [$data['start_year_month'],$data['end_year_month']])
                         ->groupBy(DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(deliver_date,"%Y-%m")'))
                         ->get();
```

Comment: You save my time Thanks a lot

Comment: @smitaranipatil plz give me an example?

Comment: $get_details=DB::select('SELECT sum(orders_qty) as sum_of_qty,deliver_date FROM `orders` WHERE deliver_date between ? AND ? GROUP BY deliver_date',['2020-02-01','2020-02-05']);  just like in your query how can i add manual date

Comment: @smitaranipatil do u means `$data['start_date'],$data['end_date']`, this variables are php variables, you can use php inbuilt method or Carbon to change to the format that u want.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this!

```
 $results = DB::table('orders')
       ->select(DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(deliver_date,"%y-%m") as deliver_date'),DB::raw('SUM(orders_qty) as sum_of_qty'))
      ->whereBetween('deliver_date',[$data['start_year_month'],$data['end_year_month']])
     ->groupBy(function ($val) {
return Carbon::parse($val->start_time)->format('y');  });
```